# How can I turn off any kind of fanciness/animations on Samsung A7, with Android 8.0.0?

Tags: samsung, settings, 8.0-oreo

I am a more or less a nostalgic type of user and what I really would like is to turn of any kind fanciness as much as possible on an/any kind of mobile phone what I have so far.

But the problem is: How can I do this?

With fanciness or fancy stuff I really mean something like moving something smoothly (or continues), or an open/close animation, or moving some unnecessary stuff on screen etc. etc.

Like in [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8NMLuVQ0UA0) video e.g. at the beginning. I would really like to change the slide instant when I swipe left/right.

Or e.g. [here](https://medium.com/@jim.zack.hu/android-inbox-material-transitions-for-recyclerview-71fc7326bcb5) the first gif on the page. It can (for my flavor) slide horizontally/vertically but to open the split e.g. instant (without wait to long).

Here are two more examples what I mean:

In Windows XP minimizing/maximizing of a window was instant, see [here](https://youtu.be/aoFofvHDjZE?t=34) e.g. and on Mac OS the min/max-ing of a window looks like [here](https://youtu.be/ZAwW6BCoaOU?t=34).

If you ask yourself 'why' then I can only say that I really mean this seriously. No, seriously, I really would like to have things happen more or less instant and not when the animation is done or what ever.

Update #1

If this can be applied only to my phone (Samsung A7, with Android 8.0.0) it would be fine too.

Update #2

I have already unlocked the developer options in the settings and also disabled the animations (see [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o0JbT.jpg)). But is it possible to disable these kind of animations in other apps too?

Comment: @beeshyams I have added my phone too, also see the tags. Also my assumption was that this can be applied to any Android phone, but **one** phone would be enough (for me at least).

Comment: Fixed the title :-) but still suggest to narrow the scope

Comment: Usually there's a setting for disabling animation on Developer Options (because many UI automated testing frameworks recommend to disable animation to prevent false positive issues). You might need to find how to turn on developer options on your device though...

Comment: @AndrewT. Thank you for this suggestion. The animation in developer options are already deactivated. But is it also possible to turn any kind of animations in other applications itself too?